# Introducing Sass Modules - problem sass-migrator

Tags: sass

How to compile sass modules(new version of sass)?
https://css-tricks.com/introducing-sass-modules/

I tried the sass-migrator terminal but it didn't compile
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/cli/migrator

sent me a message "**Nothing to migrate!**"

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error message. If you are in the same situation than I was:

- Installed sass-migrator as a global npm package (`npm install -g sass-migrator`)
- Don't have Dart installed
- On Windows (I don't know if this is relevant though)

Then this is probably because you need Dart installed on your machine, as the tool is built on top of it.

Installing `sass-migrator` with [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) solves the problem, as it automatically installs Dart along the package. Once chocolatey is installed, run the command `choco install sass-migrator`. It will add the command to your path as `sass-migrator.exe`.

*The commands were taken from [sass migrator's docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/cli/migrator#migrations).*

---

**Note:** As of writing (August 2020), there's a bug with chocolatey's sass-migrator installation that will prevent you from running `sass-migrator` on Windows. The solution, very simple, is described here: [Github issue](https://github.com/sass/migrator/issues/146).